# loop condition with variable input with scanf - C

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int n0;

    scanf("%d", &n0);
    const unsigned int n = n0;
    short unsigned int A[n];
    short unsigned int d, x, y, k;
    short int l, r;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &d);
    for (i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm a total newbie with C and stumbled across a situation that amazed me a lot. In the above code, I would like to ask the user to input some number `d`, and then to input `d` pairs of point coordinates. But to my surprise the program ends executing after inputting first pair of (x,y), no matter what value of `d` greater than 1 is input first. It doesn't happen if I assign value to `d` in code (e.x. `d = 5;`). What may be the reason? Is the value assigned to the variable via the `scanf` statement somehow different and cannot be used in a loop condition?

Comment: What does this `for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}` mean?

Comment: @xing, it worked, thanks!. But why actually %d doesn't work?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk, it is something for further functionality, I forgot to delete it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the warnings that you get when compiling your code. One of the warnings should be as follows:

> ```
> a.c:19:12: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
>      'unsigned short *' [-Wformat]
> scanf("%d",&d);
>       ~~  ^~
>       %hd
> ```

Using `%d` causes `scanf` cast a pointer to `short` as a pointer to `int`, leading to undefined behavior. It looks like in your case the upper portion of an `int` gets stored in a `short`, while the bottom portion gets dropped. For numbers undef 2<sup>16</sup> the upper part is zero, so the subsequent loop iterates zero times.

Fixing all warnings will eliminate this problem

```
scanf("%hu", &d);
... // Fix other scanf calls as well.
```

**Note:** There is no good reason for making loop variables `short`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation!